# How to check if a binary tree has mirror symmetery in its stucture (not values)

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, binary-tree, mirror, symmetric

I am asked to write a recursive algorithm which checks if a binary tree has mirror symmetry in its structure (not values). For example:

```
        1
       / \
      /   \
     /     \
     3      5
    / \    / \
    7  9  11 13
       /   \
      15   17
```

Has symmetrical structure. I would appreciate an expert eye to help me. Thanks in advance.
I know how to check if the values are symmetric but not the actual structure.

Comment: Isn’t it just a matter of tracking lefts and rights?

Comment: One approach is a recursive function with signature `bool isMirrored(struct node *left, struct node *right)` which is called as `bool result = isMirrored(root->left, root->right);` And the general idea is a dual DFS that simultaneously traverses the left and right subtrees.

Comment: What have you tried? Add current approach/code

Comment: If you know how to check if the values are symmetric, just assume the values on each node are all zero and do the check

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a class `Node` with `left` and `right` properties, the required function could look like this in Python:

```py
def is_mirror(left, right):
    if left is None or right is None:  # Either one is None
        return left == right  # True when both are None
    return is_mirror(left.left, right.right) and is_mirror(left.right, right.left)
```

You would call it like this:

```py
# Create the example tree from the question:
tree = Node(1,
    Node(3,
        Node(7),
        Node(9,
            Node(15)
        )
    ),
    Node(5,
        Node(11,
            None,
            Node(17)
        ),
        Node(13)
    )
)

print(is_mirror(tree.left, tree.right))  # True
```